# Singular values of self-adjoint operators

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

[image]

How to prove the inequality marked in red?

In order to prove $t_2\leq t_1$, we need to verify that $\tau(\chi_{(t_1,\infty)}(A_1))\leq 1$.

Since $\|A_1\|_e=0$( $\|A_1\|_e $     is the essential norm of $A_1$), we have for any $\epsilon＞0$, $\tau(\chi_{(\epsilon,\infty)}(A_1))＜\infty$. How to check that
$\tau(\chi_{(t_1,\infty)}(A_1))\leq 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $(I-E)$ is a projection that commutes with $A$, it is easy to see that $f(A(I-E))=f(A)\,(I-E)$ for any Borel function $f$. Thus
$$
\tau\big(1_{(s,\infty)}(A(I-E))\big)=\tau\big(1_{(s,\infty)}(A)\,(I-E)\big)
\leq\tau(1_{(s,\infty)}(A)).
$$
So $\mu_1(A_1)\leq\mu_1(A)$.